# Auto generate simple or variable product description in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

I have constructed the below function to work in conjunction with a button displayed on the edit product page. It is designed to generate some description text based on the title and SKU of the product. The code works perfectly for 'simple' products, but I am struggling to get it to work for 'variable' products too.

What exactly do I need to do to get it to work correctly for both simple and variable products?

The current behaviour is:

- When triggered on a simple product, it adds the new description or updates the old one to the new one.
- When triggered on a variable product, it updates the main description, but deletes all variations which were previously set up on the product.

```
add_action('woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'update_and_save_utapd');

function update_and_save_utapd() {
    
    if(isset($_POST['button_new_update_description'])){

        $product_id = wc_get_product(get_the_ID());
        $wcProduct = new WC_Product($product_id);

        $get_title = $wcProduct->get_name();
        $get_mpn = $wcProduct->get_meta('sp_wc_barcode_field');

        $get_description = $wcProduct->get_description();
        $output = '';
            
        if(!empty($get_title)){

            $output .= "<p>The " . $get_title;
        
        }if(!empty($get_mpn)){
        
            $output .= " (MPN: " . $get_mpn . ").";
        
        }if(!empty($get_description)){
                
            $wcProduct->set_description($output);
            $wcProduct->save();
        
            return "<div>SUCCESS: YOU HAVE UPDATED YOUR DESCRIPTION.</div>";  
        
        }elseif(empty($get_description)){  
        
            $wcProduct->set_description($output);
            $wcProduct->save();
            
            return "<div>SUCCESS: YOU HAVE GENERATED A NEW DESCRIPTION.</div>";
        
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want only the variable and simple product descriptions to be updated, excluding product variations? If yes, you can add a simple control `$product->is_type("simple") || $product->is_type("variable")`.

Comment: @Vdgaetano - So this?

```
add_action('woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'update_and_save_utapd');

function update_and_save_utapd() {
    
    if(isset($_POST['button_new_update_description'])){

        $product->is_type("simple") || $product->is_type("variable")
        $product_id = wc_get_product(get_the_ID());
        $wcProduct = new WC_Product($product_id);

        $get_title = $wcProduct->get_name();
        $get_mpn = $wcProduct->get_meta('sp_wc_barcode_field');

        $get_description = $wcProduct->get_description();
        $output = '';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First when using action hooks in backend that save product data, you can't return a string (a text) as you are trying to do and anyway, it will never be displayed

Now since WooCommerce 3 you can use `woocommerce_admin_process_product_object` much better hook that include the `WC_Product` Object as function argument and there is no need to use `save()` method at the end of your code as once this hook is triggered the save() method is auto applied.

So we can simplify your code:

```
add_action('woocommerce_admin_process_product_object', 'update_and_save_utapd');
function update_and_save_utapd( $product ) {
    if( isset($_POST['button_new_update_description']) ){
        $name    = $product->get_name();
        $barcode = $product->get_meta('sp_wc_barcode_field');
        $output  = '';
            
        if ( ! empty($name) ) {
            $output .= "<p>The " . $name;
        } 
        
        if ( ! empty($barcode) ) {
            $output .= " (MPN: " . $barcode . ").";
        }

        $product->set_description( $output );
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). It should better work now, without throwing errors.

Comment: This is some beautiful code - Thank you so much. When you add the variations code you commented above, it works exactly as intended (although it needs ' instead of "). Your advice about the Hook choice was the turning point and since then, I have been able to improve a lot of my old code as well as finally getting this code working as intended. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 0):

With the `woocommerce_process_product_meta` hook you already have the product id and the product object available. [Here](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-admin-class-wc-admin-meta-boxes.html#source-view.222) you will find more information.

To verify that the button has been clicked you must also check its value, in addition to the `isset()` function.

> Replace `value_button` with the value of the element's `value`
> attribute

```
add_action('woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'update_and_save_utapd', 10, 2 );
function update_and_save_utapd( $product_id, $product ) {
    // replace "value_button" with the value of the element's "value" attribute
    if ( isset( $_POST['button_new_update_description'] ) && $_POST['button_new_update_description'] == 'value_button' ) {
        if ( $product->is_type('simple') || $product->is_type('variable') ) {
            $title       = $product->get_name();
            $mpn         = $product->get_meta('sp_wc_barcode_field');
            $description = $product->get_description();
            $output      = '';

            if ( ! empty($title) ) {
                $output .= "<p>The " . $title;
            }

            if ( ! empty($mpn) ) {
                $output .= " (MPN: " . $mpn . ").";
            }
            
            if ( ! empty($get_description) ) {
                $product->set_description($output);
                $product->save();
                return "<div>SUCCESS: YOU HAVE UPDATED YOUR DESCRIPTION.</div>";  
            } else { 
                $product->set_description($output);
                $product->save();
                return "<div>SUCCESS: YOU HAVE GENERATED A NEW DESCRIPTION.</div>";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I've converted my code to use all of the information you have given me and I'm now getting the following error: ```PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function UmbrellaTrading_save_product_data_fields_utapd(), 1 passed in /var/www/vhosts/umbrellatrading.co.uk/httpdocs/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 289 and exactly 2 expected in /var/www/vhosts/umbrellatrading.co.uk/httpdocs/wp-content/themes/umbrella-trading/functions.php:498```

Comment: I believe it does not like ```function update_and_save_utapd( $product_id, $product )```

Comment: @LionHeartNerd It doesn't return any errors to me. Try checking the line `add_action ('woocommerce_process_product_meta' ...`. Check that there are priority and number of arguments.